# Build a docker for PySide6

Tags: python, docker, qt, pyside6

I have a python application that makes use of PySide6. I am able to run this locally.

Now, I am moving this to docker so that all other contributors need not install packages and libraries required individually.

Here is my "Dockerfile":

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.11

# Set the working directory in the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Note: Adding libxcb-cursor0, libegl1, and other dependencies for PySide6 and the XCB platform plugin
# Install necessary system dependencies for running a PySide6 application
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libgl1-mesa-glx \
    libxkbcommon-x11-0 \
    libxcb-icccm4 \
    libxcb-image0 \
    libxcb-keysyms1 \
    libxcb-randr0 \
    libxcb-render-util0 \
    libxcb-render0 \
    libxcb-shape0 \
    libxcb-sync1 \
    libxcb-xfixes0 \
    libxcb-xinerama0 \
    libxcb-xkb1 \
    libxcb1 \
    libxrender1 \
    libxi6 \
    libdbus-1-3 \
    libxcb-cursor0 \
    libegl1 \  
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PySide6 without specifying a version to get the latest
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install PySide6

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME MockTOEFL

# Command to run the application
CMD ["python", "Reading/temp.py"]
```

Here is the command I am using to build and run the docker:

```
docker build -t my_application . 
docker run my_application
```

I am facing the below error during run:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: From 6.5.0, xcb-cursor0 or libxcb-cursor0 is needed to load the Qt xcb platform plugin.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: linuxfb, vkkhrdisplay, wayland, minimalegl, xcb, minimal, offscreen, eglfs, vnc, wayland-egl.
```

Comment: Running graphical applications in a Docker container requires some extra things to do.

Comment: You might look at the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/), if you haven't already.  You should be able to create a package that can be `pip install`ed as a single command.  The OS packages you list seem like they should be preinstalled on an ordinary Linux desktop system, but as @KlausD. notes they may not be functional in an isolated Docker container.